# Spring boot: Requests with an expired Cookie is still available after logging out

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, spring-security

In the spring boot project, when the user logouts, we invalidate the cookie with this block of code:

```
//name = "Token"
//value = "expired"
//age = 0
private void setExpiredCookie(HttpServletResponse response, String name, String value, int age) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
        cookie.setSecure(true); //Send cookie to the server only over an encrypted HTTPS connection
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true); //Preventing cross-site scripting attacks
        cookie.setPath("/"); //Global cookie accessible every where
        cookie.setMaxAge(age); //Deleting a cookie. I Passed the same other cookie properties when you used to set it

        response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

However, after logout, I tested my website with an application for catching the request and resending it through the repeater, with exact values, such as token and payload.

I resent a request, for example, to change the email address, and this request, **despite logging out**, is valid for 15 minutes (for the life of the original cookie).

What am I missing? Because I am properly deleting and protecting cookies.

Comment: Try `HttpSession.invalidate()` or something like this

Answer (score 0):

You are just creating new cookie.
You should invalidate cookie with session id, which was given to you when you authenticated. Simply use this:

```
HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
session.invalidate();
```

Comment: I perform authentication with JWT, I have no session in my code. When I write configure method I setted ```sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);```

Comment: Where do you sending requests, i mean in browser or using another tool ? Because this cookie.setMaxAge(age) - is flag for browser not sending expired cookies, however you can send it manually

Comment: I am using the "Burp Suite" tool, to test my website for vulnerabilities. Sending the repeated PATCH request after logout with an expired token allows me to perform such a request. I want to disable using an expired token after logging out.

Comment: As i said, in your code you're setting flags for browser not to sending cookie, however you can send it manually and your app will receive it. You have to add additional logic to disable using expired cookies. If you try to send request from your browser after invalidating cookie, cookie won't be sent.

Comment: I solved my problem with redis. When the user logout I set the JWT value into the Redis like "Jwt black list". And with each user action, I check if the current token is in this blacklist, if so, then I throw an unauthorized exception. But I think this is a bad decision because, for any request, I check the blacklist and create a load on the application. However, Redis's set method has O(1) time complexity which is IMHO pretty ok. So is my solution bad?

Comment: I don't understand what cookie has to do with JWT, can you please tell me what do you want to do ? What kind of authentication scheme do you want to implement ?